# FMDatabaseQueue (FMDB) using Swift

Tags: iphone, swift, fmdb

I've been trying to find Swift examples for FMDatabaseQueue.

All I have been able to find is Objective-C here: https://ccgus.github.io/fmdb/html/Classes/FMDatabaseQueue.html

Im not familiar with Objective-C and I'm new to Swift so I'm not sure how to port the code.

Comment: You can implement Objective-C in a Swift project. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24005242/1463604

Comment: Please use FMDB docs https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb#swift

Comment: hash3r, I've read this FMDB doc and it does not discuss FMDatabaseQueue. I need FMDatabaseQueue examples.

Comment: Nishant, I have already implemented FMDB within my application, but I'm trying to learn how to use FMDatabaseQueue which is not discussed in the link you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found what I was looking for here https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/issues/291

Answer (score 0):

There exists Swift wrappers for SQLite that may be a better fit that fmdb which can run in Swift but does not use Swift features such as type safety or error handling. See for example my GRDB.swift https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift which was heavily influenced by ccgus/fmdb.